# Iteration in Razor vs ASPX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to create a single line iteration command in my non-razor MVC view that does the following:

```
@Model.Toys.Each(@<input name="Make@{@(item.Index + 1)}" type="hidden" value="@item.Item.Make" />)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if something like this was possible I wold advice you against. It's ugly. You may take a look at [templated Razor delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx) instead.

Or a simple loop:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Toys.Length; i++) {
    <input name="Make@(i)" type="hidden" value="@Model.Toys[i].Make" />
}
```

or an editor template:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Toys)
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems that you want to rewrite this code for WebForms. So:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < Model.Toys.Length; i++) { %>
    <input name="Make<%= i %>" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.Toys[i].Make %>" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: @jfar, I agree, it's subjective. But if you try to make this work on a one liner using the `.ForEach` method it will start to look ugly to you as well I think :-) Razor Templated Razor delegates seem like a good solution for me.

Comment: True enough, the delegate solution is pretty good but I don't see anything wrong with what the OP is trying to do.  Hrm, it seems like he is in fact looking for the templated delegates...

Comment: I don't think its ugly but its written in Razor syntax. I need to rewrite the code in non-razor (so no "@")

Comment: @FloatLeft, in what other syntax do you have to rewrite it? WebForms?

Comment: @FloatLeft, well, then replace the `@` with `<% %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it: Templated Razor Delegates

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

His solution is exactly for your issue :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply create an EditorTemplate to handle objects of type Toy (naming conventions handle this, so you could simply call it toy.cshtml if that's it's strong type) and then in your view you can simply have `@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Toys)`